# Lambda timed out due to container refreshed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, containers, refresh

i have gone through the site but unable get the root cause of my issue.

we have a lambda that will run for every 50 seconds. the first run of lambda is a cold start. during the start all the necessary dependencies for the lambda are prepared ( all the interfaces ).. Lambda handler will have its own code to interact with SQS and SWF. during the first run from the cloud watch logs it is clear that it is reading the base file to get all the services. then lambda handler will start. from second run only lambda handler will get invoked after 50th second. So far everything is going smooth.
All of sudden we noticed the lambda took more than 50 seconds ( in general it finishes below 10s). log shows that lambda got timed out and freshly it started to initializing all the dependencies again.

This is not giving any clue to us as after the timeout the subsequent run works smooth. Its not good to see lambda timed out. Definitely lambda code is without errors.

Could this be any container issue? Does the container have any time period that it will keep data active till it reaches the expiry time out.

Can we able to access the container object to find out more information? we have 2 or more dev environments. this behavior is different for different environments. for some it happens for every 3 days. some time in a day it happens thrice.

if we want to understand the properties of the container object how can we do it? Is it a grey zone that only AWS can access it? Lambda code is written in c# using net core App 2.0. thought of checking the cloud trail log for this lambda during the invocation. there too i am not able to find the reason behind the timeout.

we have more than 20 lambda's for dev and 10 for test in each different regions. its not getting clear to us which lambda will time out.

Any suggestions or idea's will help me a lot???????

thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda containers will not live indefinitely. If you are seeing occasional "cold starts" then that is normal behavior. If you're running only 1 invocation at a time (i.e. you only have a single lambda instance) you can still expect to see the container recycled every few hours. In general, I understand AWS is trying to give us fewer cold starts but you can still expect to get a new container and new cold start from time to time.

Comment: thanks for the reply Macbutch. Will lambda timeout during a cold start? we added catch block hoping to catch any expection during timeout. but it didnt hit the catch block. This lambda has two main checks. one to access SSM parameter store variable and other one getting the number open SWF workflows. will request limit to these services could have caused the timeout.

Comment: I think you can usually expect a container to last for a few hours. The container will not be killed by AWS during an invocation. It could be that things are timing out for you due to some change in an API (or whatever) you are using. Do you think you're doing enough requests to hit service limits? Can you add logging (or enable x-ray) to see exactly where the time is being spent? If your lambda execution is timing out you can't expect your catch/finally clause to execute but you could extend your configured timeout while you find the source.